# ember-data handle server error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data 0.13 with rails. I have a basicinfo controller to handle basicinfo model update. update action is:

```
  update: ->
    @content.save()
    @content.on('becameInvalid', (response) ->
      alert Em.inspect(response.errors)
    )
```

basicinfo.hbs:

```
<aside class='basicinfo-aside'>
  {{#if inEditModel}}
<div class='control-group'>
  <label for='basicinfo_about_me'>{{t '.basicinfo.edit.about_me'}}</label>

  <div class='controls'>
    {{view Em.TextArea id='basicinfo_about_me'
                       class='basicinfo-about-me'
                       name='basicinfo[about_me]'
                       valueBinding='aboutMe'}}
  </div>
</div>

<div class='action-group'>
  <span {{bindAttr class=':about-me-length-remain
                          hasAboutMeLengthRemain:muted:text-error'}}>
    {{aboutMeLengthRemain}}
  </span>

  <button class='btn-cancel btn' {{action cancel}}>
    {{t '.basicinfo.edit.cancel'}}
  </button>

  <button class='btn-update btn btn-primary' {{action update}}>
    {{t '.basicinfo.edit.update'}}
  </button>
</div>

  {{/if}}
</aside>

<div class='basicinfo-inner'>
  {{#unless inEditModel}}
    <h5>
      {{t '.basicinfo.about_me'}}

      {{#if canManage}}
        <a class='lnk-edit' href='#' {{action edit}}>
          <i class='icon-edit'></i>
        </a>
      {{/if}}
    </h5>

    <p class='about-me'>{{aboutMe}}</p>
  {{/unless}}
</div>
```

when I click update button with invalid data first time the error shows properly, but if I dont fix error and press update button again Ember shows: "Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willCommit` on  while in state rootState.loaded.updated.invalid. Called with undefined " How to solve it Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ember data seems to be a little buggy when handling errors.

I would suggest you'd the following:

```
update: ->
  @content.rollback() if @content.get('isError')
  @content.save().then ((success_responce)->
    <handle success responce here>
  ), (failure)->
    <handle failure here>
```

Still a better solution in my opinion  would be to disable the update button , based on the `record.isError` flag.

Another thing to consider is what to do when the server returns errors and you want to transition to another route (like with a cancel button).
 Ember data will forbid you to ,complaining the record has inFlightAtrributes.
In this case you can again call `record.rollback()` to return the flags to initial state and continue your transition.